# Does SQL Server 2014 evaluation copy provide SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I installed SQL Server 2014 Express. It doesn't have SSIS, so I installed SQL Server 2014 evaluation. I still don't see SSIS. Am I installing it in a wrong way or does SSIS come only with purchased SQL Server 2014 Standard edition and above.

I need to load multiple flat files into a database so I can work on them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSIS IS NOT FREE !! We have to buy atleast the standard edition of Sql Server which is too costly if you are working for a small company.
Best way to load multiple files into a database without SSIS is to merge all files with same columns together in excel [Merging files](http://www.oaultimate.com/office/merge-multiple-excel-files-into-a-single-spreadsheet-ms-excel-2007.html)
and then load that big file into the database using Sql Server Import & Export.
Formatting columns may be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Express version comes without SSIS. Actually there is not free version of SSIS. You need either SQL Server Standard, Developer, or Enterprise edition to get access to BIDS. If you have Visual Studio then you can download SQL Server Data Tools and you will be able to create SSIS projects

if you have Visual Studio 2013, then download and install this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is only available in the Enterprise, Business Intelligence and Standard editions. It should be available in the evaluation though as the evaluation is based on the Enterprise version (with a 180-day trial time).

It might be that you have to explicitly select to install the component (I haven't used the trial version in many years and honestly don't remember).

See this for more information: [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc645993%28v=sql.120%29.aspx#SSIS)

Comment: I installed all components that were offered on the evaluation copy. Still I couldnt find SSIS

Comment: @AseemHegshetye Like I said, the option to install integration services should be included in the trial version. If you don't get that option I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS comes with SQL Server Developer edition which is inexpensive.  Developer comes with all the features of Enterprise I believe.